# Middleman still creating standard assets folders

Tags: debian, compile

I just installed middleman to mainly speed up my static site creation workflow. Every is working the way I want (My *.html.erb files get compiled to *.html correctly) but Middleman is still creating the javascripts, stylesheets and images folders with e.g. the middleman.png inside the images folder. But I changed the folder for the files in my config.rb:

```
activate :automatic_image_sizes
set :css_dir, 'data.main/css'
set :js_dir, 'data.main/js'
set :images_dir, 'data.main/img'
configure :build do
end
```

what am I doing wrong? Sorry for this probably stupid question, but I am new to Middleman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
activate :automatic_image_sizes
set :css_dir, '/data.main/css'
set :js_dir, '/data.main/js'
set :images_dir, '/data.main/img'
configure :build do
end
```

Fixes it...